# TypeError: descriptor 'lower' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to a 'list' object

Tags: tokenize

I wanna stemming my dataset. Before stemming, I did tokenize use nltk tokenize
You can see the output on the pic
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMiDA.png)
[Col Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThSWN.png)

But when i do stemming, it return error :

```
[Error][3]
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
    last)
    <ipython-input-102-7700a8e3235b> in <module>()
    ----> 1 df['Message'] = df['Message'].apply(stemmer.stem)
          2 df = df[['Message', 'Category']]
          3 df.head()

    5 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist- 
   packages/Sastrawi/Stemmer/Filter/TextNormalizer.py in 
    normalize_text(text)
          2 
          3 def normalize_text(text):
    ----> 4     result = str.lower(text)
          5     result = re.sub(r'[^a-z0-9 -]', ' ', result, flags = 
    re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)
          6     result = re.sub(r'( +)', ' ', result, flags = 
    re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)

    TypeError: descriptor 'lower' requires a 'str' object but received a 
    'list'
```

Hope all you guys can help me

Comment: Can you copy the text and error message from your screenshots into this post? This will help future people find this post!

Comment: @ninapavlich i already edited. can you check it?

Comment: @Marcello the quickest way to get help/feedback on your problem is to post your desired result, with a reproducible example.  See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example